# Filter Pandas dataframe one column for only True boolean values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

When I run the following code: `Pd_file[:]['raw_end_of_event']`, I get:

```
0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
4        False
         ...  
40508    False
40509    False
40510    False
40511    False
40512    False
```

Some of the rows are `True`, and I would like to filter for those rows. Any idea how I would achieve this, and let me know please if I have not given enough information.

Comment: Use `Pd_file[Pd_file['raw_end_of_event']]`

Comment: It doesn't work- it returns all of the columns, with just the last row

Comment: Syntax error... I don't get it. The column is called `raw_end_of_event`

Comment: So need `Pd_file.loc[Pd_file['raw_end_of_event'], 'raw_end_of_event']` ?

Comment: Okay, but I don't assign `True` anywhere?- I only want the rows with True

Comment: If got only one row it means there is one `True`, check number of Trues by `print (Pd_file['raw_end_of_event'].sum())`